# spinner adapter and Listview adapter

Tags: android-widget

I have a ListActivity with a setListAdapter call so that I can dynamically hide buttons in the listview. This was working fine till I introduced a spinner which now works fine but somehow stops the listview adapter from working without producing any debug issues or crashes so the buttons are no longer being hidden where they should.

Has anyone come across this and resolved it before?

```
...oncreate() {
...

ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> spinadapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.order_by_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    spinadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(spinadapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());


}



private void updateData() {

...        
    MySimpleArrayAdapter adapter = new MySimpleArrayAdapter(this, mp3, titles, artists);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered what was happening here, there was no conflict, I just forgot to call the pertinent method after the spinner was selected.